# Contact form 7 does not email if dollar used in dropdown

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 plugin to create form in wordpress. In that form I have many fields, out of which all are not compulsory & after submitting the form an email is sent. One of them is Drop-down(Which is not a compulsory field) having values ranging from $5,000 to $10,000, like

```
$5000

$7000

$5969
```

Now I have 3 cases:

1. If I select any of these values from drop down and submit the form it shows that `form has been submitted successfully` but I don't receive any email.
2. Whereas, If I *do not* select anything from Drop-down (as it is not compulsory field) then I *do* receive an email.
3. If I remove `$` and just keep simple numbers in the drop down, I receive an email no matter what.

So I want to ask whether contact form 7 doesn't accept `$` or what could be the issue ?

It is preferable if I keep `$`.

Thankyou

Comment: Can you try to replace the `$` with its HTML entity: `&#36;`? I'm curious what happens if you do this.

Comment: Added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer. My hunch was that the validation didn't like the actual `$` symbol. Instead, using the HTML entity `&#36;` works.